# group_concat duplicate values

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, group-concat

I wrote two queries to concat values with different conditions, the results of two queries should be same,but I couldn't get correct result with query2.The two queries are as follows:

query1:

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(f.NAME, ';') , sgk.NAME),' ') ,cc.operator),' ')) as res_string
FROM complex_check_anag cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check_anag sgk,functionalci f ,lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg 
WHERE cc.complex_check_id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.single_check_id = lk.single_check_id and f.id = lkcg.config_item_id
and sgk.single_check_id = lkcg.single_check_id and sgk.status = 'active' GROUP BY cc.NAME
```

with query1 I can get the following result:

```
res_string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
MIL04DNS01;memory check and ,MIL04DNS01;cpu_check and 
MIL04APPBOXIP01;cpu_check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;memory check and
Sito_Saturn_Secure;log in check and
```

Query2:

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(f.NAME, ';') , sgk.NAME),' ') ,cc.operator),' ')) as res_string 
FROM complex_check_anag cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check_anag sgk,functionalci f ,lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg,comp_t_anag cmt
WHERE cc.complex_check_id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.single_check_id = lk.single_check_id and f.id = lkcg.config_item_id 
and sgk.single_check_id = lkcg.single_check_id and sgk.status = 'active' and cc.complex_check_id <> cmt.comp_o_id GROUP BY sgk.NAME
```

with query2 I can get the following result:

```
res_string
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MIL04DNS01;memory check and ,MIL04DNS01;cpu_check and ,MIL04DNS01;memory check and ,MIL04DNS01;cpu_check and ,MIL04DNS01;memory check and ,MIL04DNS01;cpu_check and
MIL04APPBOXIP01;cpu_check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;memory check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;cpu_check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;memory check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;cpu_check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;memory check and 
Sito_Saturn_Secure;log in check and ,Sito_Saturn_Secure;log in check and ,Sito_Saturn_Secure;log in check and and ,MIL04DNS01;memory check and ,MIL04APPBOXIP01;memory check and
```

could you give me some suffestions to modify the query2 to get the same result with query1 ?...Thanks a lot .

Comment: Just fyi, I don't even consider looking at the queries as long as they are formatted like this. Actually they aren't formatted at all. And while you're at it, you could familiarize yourself with the join syntax that was made standard in 1992 and use it right away. It's just an unreadable mess.

Comment: could you provide sqlfiddle with data sample please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestion to you:

1. `CONCAT` function accept as many parameters as you wish, so you don't need to `concat(concat(concat...`
2. You should never use `FROM tbl1,tbl2,tbl3...` when `JOIN` tables. It should be clearly set by `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` with `ON` rule(s).
3. Here my guess how your query should be like. But I have some problems to understand how last table `comp_t_anag cmt` must be joined. I don't see real key to join that table. And I did `LEFT JOIN` for all tables, maybe you need `INNER` somewhere, so you can play with that.

> ```
>  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(f.NAME, ';', sgk.NAME,' ',cc.operator,' ')) as res_string 
>  FROM complex_check_anag cc
>  LEFT JOIN lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk
>  ON cc.complex_check_id = lk.complex_check_id 
>  LEFT JOIN  single_check_anag sgk
>  ON sgk.single_check_id = lk.single_check_id
>    AND sgk.status = 'active'
>  LEFT JOIN lnkconfigurationitemtosinglecheck lkcg
>  ON sgk.single_check_id = lkcg.single_check_id 
>  LEFT JOIN functionalci f 
>  ON  f.id = lkcg.config_item_id 
>  LEFT JOIN comp_t_anag cmt
>  ON cc.complex_check_id <> cmt.comp_o_id
>  GROUP BY sgk.NAME
> ```